# Plotting code does not work as supposed

Tags: r, plot

I'm interested in making two plots showing test results based on a test I have made.
In the test I have stored 3 vectors:

- a vector R containing 1 for a correct answer, -1 for an incorrect answer and 0 for unanswered questions
- a vector Q that contains questions collected in a cell-array Q so that each element of Q contains one question.
- a vector T which contains the time spend on answering a question and has also the same ordering as Q and R.

An exemple of those could be:

```
R = [1 -1 1 1]
Q = {'Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'}
T = [5.22 5.44 7.23 2.33]
```

The plots I will make is:

- "Time vs. score" - A plot with the time on the x-axis and the score on the y-axis. 
     The x-axis start with 0 and ends with the time a user choose the last answer. 
     Score is a cumulative score of the results, where a correct answer gives 1 point, 
     and an incorrect answer gives -1 point.
- "Question number vs. time" - A bar plot with the question number on the x-axis and the 
      time on the y-axis. The x-axis shows the questions in the order they were asked. 
      The y-axis shows the time spent on a question. The correct and incorrect answers 
      are distinguished using different colors.

My current code is this, but it does not work as supposed:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(T,R)
title('Time vs. score')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Score')
grid on


subplot(2,1,2)
bar(T,colorcodeF)
title('Question number vs. time')
xlabel('Question number')
ylabel('Time')
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. What doesn't it do correctly? What kind of errors do you get? Please provide a reproducible example, including code and example data.

Comment: Thank you very much.Well I don't get any errors. The problem is, that I can't figure out how to accomplish making the plots as specified.

Comment: What would help is a sample of your data (see `?dput`), and a mockup of how the plot should look like (at least, for me, this is much clearer than a description of the plot in words). You can create the mockup for example in paint or any other drawing program.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a less informative title and it's hard to come up with something.  Please put some time into making a decent title next time.

Comment: @Dason I don't think next time.  Please change the title to something that is searcherable and specific.  Otherwise this question is not likely to benefit future searchers and ought to be closed.  I think reading the post guidelines could help as this problem is not reproducible either: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

"Question number vs. time" could be solved with ggplot2 like this

```
R <- c(1, -1, 1, 1)
Q <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
T <- c(5.22, 5.44, 7.23, 2.33)
D <- data.frame(R, Q, T)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(D, aes(Q,T)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=factor(R)))
```

Regarding "Time vs. score", I do not quite understand what you're trying to plot. Maybe you would like something like this

```
ggplot(D, aes(T[order(T)], cumsum(R[order(T)]))) + geom_point()
```

As a remark to @user3598942, the title of the question isn't very informative :(